# Finding dates and storing ranges in variables

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to find "blocks" in the worksheet that have dates in the A-column. A block is seperated by lines as you can see from the picture. The whole file is full of these blocks but I only need the blocks that have dates in the A-column. Just to be clear I don't just need the rows with the dates but the full block that contains the date.

A block in my files for example is the Range `A172:G192`. 
Picture of the file:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

How should I continue after selecting the first block? I probably should use the Find function starting from row 184 or the row of ResultDown variable moving down the sheet on "A" Column. However the row needs to be dynamic, so I can use it for the next block. Also I have no idea how many blocks there will be, so I would like to hear from you how to solve this aswell.

I would like to save all the blocks as different variables and then hide all the blocks in the worksheet and then just unhide the blocks that I stored in the variables.

My biggest problem is the last row.

```
Result2 = Range(Cells(StartcellRow, 1), Cells(1000, 1)).Find(What:="**/**/****", After:=Range(Cells(StartcellRow, 1))).Select
```

I keep getting an runtime error 1004

```
 Public Sub FB_MAKRO()

    Dim FBwb As Workbook
    Dim FBsht As Worksheet
    Dim ACol As Range



'Set variables for workbook and sheet

    Set FBwb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\l000xxx\Desktop\Makrot\FORCED BALANCE MAKRO\FB HARJOITUS.xls")
    Set FBsht = FBwb.Sheets("Forced Balance")
    Set ACol = FBsht.Range("A1:A1000")

'I want ACol variable to be the entire A-Column. Any ideas?
'For some reason the range function is not working here?





'This locates the date in A'column, so I can select the correct block

    Result = Range("A3:A1000").Find(What:="**/**/****", After:=Range("A3")).Address


'This is the top left corner of the Block1 selection

    ResultUp = Range(Result).End(xlUp).Offset(-1, 0).Address
    Range(ResultUp).End(xlDown).Select
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell).End(xlDown).Select

'The ResultsDownLastRow variable is for Block2 find function
'ResultDown is the bottom right corner of the Block1

    ResultsDownLastRow = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell).End(xlDown).Address
    ResultDown = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell).End(xlDown).Offset(-2, 6).Address

'First Block assigned. I plan to use this in the end when I hide everything and then unhide these blocks

    Block1 = Range(ResultUp, ResultDown).Select


' NEXT BLOCK STARTS HERE

'StartCellRow is the cell that the find function should start looking for Block2
'Result2 is the find function for Block2


    StartcellRow = Range(ResultsDownLastRow).Row


    Result2 = Range(Cells(StartcellRow, 1), Cells(1000, 1)).Find(What:="**/**/****", After:=Range(Cells(StartcellRow, 1))).Select



End Sub
```

'This returns value 194

```
StartcellRow = Range(ResultsDownLastRow).Row MsgBox StartcellRow
```

'This should work but doesn't. I get a syntax error

```
Range(Cells(StartcellRow &","& 1),Cells(1000 & "," & 1)).Find(What:="**/**/****", After:=Range(Cells(StartcellRow& ","& 1)).Select
```

This doesn't work either

'StarcellRow gives out value of 194

```
StartcellRow = Range(ResultsDownLastRow).Row

Result2 = Range("A&:StartcellRow:A648").Find(What:="**/**/****", After:=Range("A&:StartcellRow")).Select
```

This doesn't give me a syntax error but it's not working

Comment: `*` matches any number (0 or more) of character. So `**/**/****` is the same as `*/*/*`. Maybe `??/??/????` will be better?

Comment: **/**/**** works just fine the first time. I keep getting an error on the second block.

Comment: I understand the A column part. But got 1 question. According to your image, dates are only in `A174:184` (11 rows, 1 column). So the block that you want to copy or do something, would it be `C174:G184` (11 rows, 5 columns)??? I just want to know if the row numbers that contains dates can be used later on selecting the block you want (in your image, those numbers would be 174 to 184).

Comment: @Usurper Please, do not post code as a comment. It's better if you edit your question and add the code and an explanation :)

Comment: The dates are located in A column. There are several blocks that some have dates and some don't. I just want to store the blocks that have dates as variables. In this picture my block would be A172:G192.

For finding the blocks I'm looking for Dates in A block and the selecting the area using the currency headings (EUR and GBP)

Comment: Ok, I just updated the first post. I need help with the syntax

Comment: Please note that the information is still accesable in the revision history. You will also need to flag for moderator attention. See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132117/388562) for more information. If you can't flag yet because of reputation feel free to reply with @ and I will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would search for all currency header and store their rownumber into an array. For each rownumber in the array i would look into the cell below (rownumber + 1). when there is a date in the cell, i would set the range in the following way:

```
set rangeWithDate = Range(Cells(actualRowNumberInArray - 1, 1), Cells(nextRowNumberInArray - 2, 7))
```

Array:

```
Dim array1() As long    

Redim array1(5)        
For i = 1 To 5        
    array(i) = i
Next i

Redim array1(10)        ' changes the "length" of the array, but deletes old entries 
For i = 1 To 10        
    Feld1(i) = i    
Next i  

Redim Preserve array1(15)    ' changes the "length" of the array without deleting old entries
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll try to figure this out. I don't know how arrays work